# Update github repo after local changes

Tags: git, github, push

I've updated the folder stucture of a project locally on my computer to make it way better organized. I deleted some folders, did some name changes and changed the location of files.

But now I'm not able to push the whole thing into my github repo.

Is there a method to update the repo (master branch) from my locally made changes?
Maybe `git push --force`?

I did the following steps:

```
git add .

git commit

git push
```

That leads to this error:

```
remote: error: File folder_name/logs/... is 140.24 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please describe commands that you used to init repo/commit/push your changes. errors? merge conflict? another reason?

Comment: Did you accidentally delete the .git file? What does ```git push``` result in?

Comment: You need to remove the large file from the last commit and amend the commit; creating a new commit will not help. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732917/7976758 for example.

Comment: or maybe create .gitignore file

Comment: @codegorilla It's too late, the file is already in the commit, `.gitignore` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, there is a github file size limit. Hence you should remove such files before pushing.

```
git rm -r --cached folder_name/logs 
git commit
git push
```

Now to explain, the `rm --cached` is just to remove them from the being tracked. I have avoided `git add .` command as it will add all the files again. You should run `git status` and add file accordingly.

For future cases, use `.gitignore`

```
cd /path/to/github
echo "folder_name/logs/*" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit
git status
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have permissions to do this. It is a possible reason why you can't push your changes.

Always avoid using "push --force", it is really awful practice and there are not so many cases where it is necessary.